# SSRS - How to skin the plus and minus icons in a group visibility toggle cell

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I'm using SSRS 2012 to create a report where I have groups that can be opened or closed based on the value of another textbox.

When the report is rendered SSRS displays a plus or minus icon next to that textbox to let users toggle visibility but the icons are pretty basic. I have been looking for a while now and can't seem to find a way to skin them, so I'm starting to wonder: is it possible at all? And if not, can you think of any workaround?

Many thanks!

Comment: looked for it a bit. Didn't seem to find anything that could help you out. Sorry pal, maybe try to submit a CR in [link](http://connect.microsoft.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that could help someone else, I finally went for the workaround using good old jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('img[alt="+"]').attr('src', 'customPlusImage.png');
    $('img[alt="-"]').attr('src', 'customMinusImage.png');
});
```

Let me know if you have a better way!